# ListView Data Binding for Windows 8.1 Store Apps

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

So I am trying to move a desktop program i made to an app for `Windows 8.1` using `Visual Studio 2013`.  `Datagrid` was deprecated for this release so I am trying to translate those over to a `ListView`.  I previously used `ListViews` in other desktop applications, but it looks like a lot has changed.  The problem I am having is populating my `ListView` from my database. I am connecting through a `WCF Service` and stepping through the code, I can see I am getting the right data, I just cant get it to appear in my ListView.  My preferred end result would be a 'listview' with 3 columns of information which will be editable. Previously I would use `ListView.View` and then put a `GridView` in there for the columns.  But it appears `ListView.View` is deprecated just like `GridView.Columns`.

here is my xaml for the `ListView`

```
<ListView x:Name="lvInventory" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource listViewStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="200"  Width="200">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbName" Text="{Binding InventoryName}" Width="200" Foreground="#FF0E0D0D" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="tbQty" Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="tbType" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

In my codebehind I am assigning the itemssource of my listview.

```
        VMInventory inventory = new VMInventory();            
        inventory.GetList();
        lvInventory.ItemsSource = inventory;
```

`VMInventory` is my `ViewModel` where I am getting my data from the `WCF service` and that looks like:

```
 public async Task GetList()
    {

            this.connection = new InventoryModelEntities(new Uri(url));
            var filteredList = from o in connection.Inventory
                               where o.Have == false
                               select o;
            var query = await Task.Factory.FromAsync((filteredList as DataServiceQuery).BeginExecute(null, null),
                (result) => (filteredList as DataServiceQuery).EndExecute(result)) as IEnumerable<Aurora.InventoryService.Inventory>;

            this.inventoryList = query.ToList();
            this.currentItem = 0;
            this.onPropertyChanged("Current");
            this.IsAtStart = true;
            this.IsAtEnd = (inventoryList.Count == 0);
}
```

One last side note, I was able to add a textbox to the `Grid` and when I `DataBind` it to `text="{Binding Current.InventoryName}"` I am able to successfully bind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly your UI is not getting updated with values what ever your adding in ViewModel, but if you add some value in UI it is reflecting in the ViewModel.

If that is the case, the use ObserableCollection instead of list, and if your creating list every time, then you have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel.

If you have done all this but still it is not updating then, your creating the list in asy Task, which is not a UI thread. If you want to update a UI from a non-Ui thread, then use update the UI using Dispatcher. You can find lot of examples to update the UI from non-UI thread using dispatcher

Comment: the UI is not getting updated at all, and if I make changes to the UI it is not reflected in the viewmodel.  The viewmodel is populated fine, it is just not making it to the UI. Ill try changing it to an observable collection.  re: the async Task, It will databind and display the data when I bound it to a text box using the "Current.InventoryName" binding.  But I cant use current for the LV because I need all of them, not just one.

Comment: @Kumareshan is correct, ObservableCollection is the answer. If you want to updated it from a Task (not running on the UI thread), you will need to look into CoreDispatcher, or you will get marshalling errors.

Comment: OK, I'll adjust my var query to return an ObservableCollection instead of an IEnumerable.  Once I do that, then my databindings will work they way they are?  This was much easier in WPF when I could access a database directly.

Comment: @Kumareshan, I ended up taking WCF out of the picture and using SQLite which i didnt know you could use with a window store app.  I then built my viewmodel around an observable collection, and it worked!  thanks for the help!